# Android: one BroadcastReceiver for muliple broadcast

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to have one BroacastReceiver for my application so I want all broadcast actions (wifiManger.getResultscan;connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo; and maybe other ones ) to be detected in the BoradcastListener. How can I connect the BroadcastReceiver in the MainActivity with the broadcastListner calss?

```js
 private void check_wifi_available() {
  WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);



  registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    final List<ScanResult> results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
    if (results != null) {
     // list of access points from the last scan
     List<ScanResult> updatedResults = new ArrayList<ScanResult>();
     // pick Wi-Fi access points which begins with these "SV-"
     // characters.
     for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
      String ssid = results.get(i).SSID;
      // Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^KD-(4[0-9]{2}|500)$");
      // Matcher m = p.matcher(ssid);
      // if(m.matches()){}else{}
      if (ssid.startsWith("KD")) {

       updatedResults.add(results.get(i));
      }
     }
     if (updatedResults.size() > 0) {
      String a = deliverBestAccessPoint(updatedResults);
      textWifi.setText(a.toString());
     }
    }

   }

  }, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
```

```js
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

  ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

  NetworkInfo netInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

  boolean isConnected = netInfo != null
    && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
  if (isConnected) {
   Toast.makeText(context, "The device is connected to the internet ",
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   Log.i("NET", "connecte" + isConnected);
  } else {
   Toast.makeText(context,
     "Please connect the device to the internet.",
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

First Create a receiver variable

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     //Compare intent.getAction() with your required intents
}
```

Then call registerReceiver

```
registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(other required intent filter constants));
```

Comment: shall I craete this  receiver variable in the"BroadcastListener" class or in the MainActivity?

Comment: This variable would go in your activity and it itself would take care of listening to your broadcasts so you would not need the BroadCastListener class anymore

Comment: For all registerReceivers shall I use the the same receiver variable or shall I create receiver1 und receiver2 variables?

Comment: The same receiver variable; you can compare each of the received intent and take necessary steps accordingly

Comment: I dont understand ur approach because I have different onReceive methode. Please see my updated question and adjust your answer to my update to comprehend your approach. Thanks

Comment: shall I put the logic of the both onReceive() methods in the onReceive method of the receiver variable?

Answer (score 0):

Just create IntentFilter separately and add all actions you want to handle:

```
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("action1");
    intentFilter.addAction("action2");
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // I have this one here to dectect wifi access points (getResultScan)
        }, intentFilter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class in your package name;

```
public class DiscoDancer extends BroadcastReceiver {

       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

      //check here with, intent.getAction() and macth with your action

       }
    }
```

In your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="DiscoDancer">
      <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED">
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW">
    //Add all the intents here

      </action>
      </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Is that the best way to handle system broadcast also for each broadcast I shall craete a new class that extends BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: you don't need to create a new class, you can use the same class check the action you get in onReceieve.